# How to Retrieve a Bitmap Arraylist from the sdcard

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmap

Here, I break the image in to 9*9 pieces, placed all the pieces in an array like this, ArrayList values. Then next I stored those ArrayList value in the sdcard successfully. Here my Question is how to retrieve those ArrayList value, and in that Arraylist value contains some break images. Below you can observe details.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap>   cut = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(number_bixs);
        Bitmap Bb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bsbmp, width,height, true);
        rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(number_bixs);
        hgt = Bb.getHeight() / rows;
        wdt = Bb.getWidth() / cols;
        int yaxis = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            int xaxis = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
                cut.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(Bb, xaxis, yaxis, wdt, hgt));
                xaxis += wdt;
            }
}
```

here below code stored that ArrayList value in the sdcard.

```
File FracturedDirectory = new File(
                 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                         + "/Fractured photoes/");
         FracturedDirectory.mkdirs();

         try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                     .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                     + "/Fractured photoes/" + cut);


            selectedphoto_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

Then now, How can i retrieve those ArrayList value "cut" from the sdcard and store those in one more/ another  ArrayList value.
Any suggestions thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things wrong.

First, you should give a name to each bitmap in the arraylist (it could be as simple as 0.png, 1.png, 2.png etc. depending on the position of the bitmap in the arraylist) and pass the individual names to the FileOutputStream() constructor instead of passing `cut`. Passing `cut` makes no sense as the mentioned constructor should receive a single file name.

Don't forget to call `out.close()` after `selectedphoto_bitmap.compress(...)`.

In order to read the bitmaps you can do something similar to this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
    cut.add(bitmap);
}
```